# Understanding indices in Neo4j - why is resampling necessary?

Tags: indexing, neo4j

At https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.3/performance/statistics-execution-plans/, we see the following table: 
[image]

> Controls the percentage of the index that has to have been updated
>   before a new sampling run is triggered.

What does "sampling" mean? Why do updates invalidate the index? I know indices from relational databases and in this case there is no need to maintain indices (adding/deleting row corresponds to adding/deleting node in some BTree).

Could someone why resampling of indices in Neo4j is necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The index is always valid.

Periodic sampling generates statistics used by the Cypher execution planner, so that is can generate plans that are more optimal for the current state of the DB.

To quote from the [operations manual](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.3/performance/statistics-execution-plans/#statistics-execution-plans) (a little earlier than the table in your question):

> When a Cypher query is issued, it gets compiled to an execution plan
>   that can run and answer the query. The Cypher query engine uses
>   available information about the database, such as schema information
>   about which indexes and constraints exist in the database. Neo4j also
>   uses statistical information about the database to optimize the
>   execution plan.

Comment: This is correct. To elaborate a bit, consider in a MATCH query if multiple nodes could be obtained by index lookup to be starting points. The planner uses the statistics from these samplings to determine which approach is likely better (one node, the other node, or both and do a hash join), plus there's always situations where the planner could use different indexes to perform the lookup on the same node, and needs to know which is likely to be more selective.